# Trojan in my VB application

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control, virus, trojan

I recently sent my application to a friend and to my surprise, he told me that he was with a Trojan. I checked the file in Virus Total and the site reported these things to me. Does anyone know how to solve it?

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Is your app downloading come content from internet to ur pc?

Comment: Did you obfuscate your application?

Comment: It's possible 2 engine reports are false positive. Do you using something that may trigger false positive for them?

Comment: I'm use webbrowser from navigate just to Netflix page and I don't know what is obfuscate.